# Using SCIP as the solver for Pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo, scip

I'm a total novice at adding solvers to Pyomo that don't just have a conda or pip install like gurobi. I'm trying to install SCIP and interface it with Pyomo. I have the scipampl-6.0.0.win.x86_64.intel.opt.spx2.exe and I'm wondering where to put it in my computer (does it need to live in the folder where my scripts are?) and how to add it to my path/Anaconda prompt or whatever I need to do so I can set solver=SolverFactory('scipampl'). If anyone could give a set of instructions (more detailed than "add it to your path") or point me towards an existing tutorial, it would be much appreciated.

I'm using Python 3.7, Pyomo 5.6.10 and I run everything through the Anaconda Prompt window not the command line.

Edit: I tried using sys.append.path('C:\...\SCIP') and 
SolverFactory(scip,'C:\...\SCIP\scipampl') and it seems to be working. I would still love guidance on how to make this a permanent thing within my Anaconda Prompt framework.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I posted an answer at https://or.stackexchange.com/a/9802/5262.

Since you're using Anaconda, the easiest thing is probably to use `conda install scip`, which will install the `scip` executable on your search path. As of SCIP 8 (maybe earlier), the same executable is used for running SCIP with its own interface or using the AMPL interface.

I think Pyomo in theory has a way to communicate with SCIP via its own interface when you use `--solver scip` and don't specify `--solver-io`. But I got errors when I did that. So instead I force Pyomo to use the AMPL interface by specifying `pyomo --solver scip --solver-io nl model.py` or using `SolverFactory('scip', solver_io='nl')` in Python code.

You may also be able to get your downloaded binary to work by specifying `pyomo --solver '\path\to\scipampl-6.0.0.win.x86_64.intel.opt.spx2.exe' model.py` or using `SolverFactory(solver='scip', executable='\path\to\scipampl-6.0.0.win.x86_64.intel.opt.spx2.exe', solver_io='nl')`.